# PHP server terminated unexpectedly (Symfony)

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I've just started to learn Symfony framework and I noticed that almost every time there is some meaningful error in my code (for example I missed some "use" statement) my server terminates unexpectedly and I don't know how to get any information about what exactly caused it.

Most of the time I was able to figure it out on my own, but now I've just started to use Doctrine and I want to save some object to the database, but when I run the code my server terminates. I figured out that the "flush()" method is causing the problem, but now I'm stuck as I can't get any more information about the error. So I actually have two questions - how can I get more information about errors like this and how to solve this particiular one?

The codes are below:

The controller

```
/* UserController.php */
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/user/test")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setLogin("Test");
        $user->setEmail("test@test.com");
        $user->setPassword(hash("sha256", "test"));
        $user->setJoined(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $user->setActivationCode(NULL);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush(); /* The line that causes server to terminate! */
        return new Response("Hello");
    }
}
```

And the entity

```
/* User.php (Entity) */

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $login;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $joined;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=TRUE)
     */
    private $activation_code;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set login
     *
     * @param string $login
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLogin($login)
    {
        $this->login = $login;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get login
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set joined
     *
     * @param \DateTime $joined
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setJoined($joined)
    {
        $this->joined = $joined;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get joined
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getJoined()
    {
        return $this->joined;
    }

    /**
     * Set activationCode
     *
     * @param string $activationCode
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setActivationCode($activationCode)
    {
        $this->activation_code = $activationCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activationCode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActivationCode()
    {
        return $this->activation_code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your Symfony logs. Turn on PHP logging if it is not on and then check that log after repeating the error. If you are using the PHP server set it up in Apache instead and then you will have logging there also.

Comment: Thak you, that really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use `web/app_dev.php` as your endpoint.
So your url will be like `localhost:8000/app_dev.php/<your-routing-alias>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in this case even when I use app_dev.php the server still terminates and I still can't get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web browser to access your Symfony instance on a remote host - I mean a machine that is not the 'localhost'? If so, you'll need to edit the 'web/app_dev.php' file where it has a line like so:

```
|| !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['192.168.40.208', '192.168.255.74',
            '127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
```

Enter in the IP address of the remote host that you are trying to access your web URL from. Using the DEV URL: of "http://ip_address/app_dev.php/" would be the best way to troubleshoot.

You'll see useful help information when you use this link - I highly recommend it.

I also notice this one line:

```
@ORM\Table(name="`user`")
```

I'm not sure if you need those backticks. Try this:

```
@ORM\Table(name="user")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using localhost and using the dev enviroment didn't help. Also I think it's in dev enviroment by default (?). And the backticks are necessary because "user" is the MySql reserved word. However I managed to resolve my problem by checking the php logs file. It turned out that I had to create the datetime object instead of providing the date as a string.

Comment: Hi - that is incorrect. I have the same annotations `@ORM\Table(name="user")` and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe, but in the Doctrine documentation it says you should backtick MySql reserved words so I just didn't want to take the risk. It works fine with backticks, too.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and after a lot of investigation discovered the date was causing my issue. I can see this is an old question, but the answer may help someone.

It looks like Doctrine requires a full date time object when inserting into a datetime / datetimetz field:

Try replacing

```
$user->setJoined(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

With

```
$user->setJoined(new \DateTime("now"));
```